# matlab unable to find proper locale

Tags: 14.04, matlab, locale

I have installed matlab R2015a on Ubuntu 14.04.2.

Upon starting matlab and whenever I am trying to load a `.m` file I get the following error:

```
Caught "std::exception" Exception message is:
locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

I have followed the suggestion found on the Internet to rebuilt the locales.

I have also modified the contents of the following files to be:

`cat /etc/default/locale`

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

`cat /etc/environment`

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

`cat $HOME/.pam_environment`

```
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Finally the output of the `locale` command is:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Is there anything more I can try?

Comment: You may want to check out [this MATLAB answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/126994-locale-system-error).

Comment: Thank you, this one worked. After start up, I run `setenv('LC_ALL','C')` and then I can open `.m` files without an issue

Comment: Good. Then, if I was you, I'd remove `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` from `/etc/default/locale` and `/etc/environment`. I'd also remove the `~/.pam_environment` file completely. With those changes, the GUIs for controlling languages and locales would work as expected if you ever want to use them. Currently they don't.

Comment: Your last suggestion solved the problem for good. Now, I do not even get the error on startup and I can open `.m` files without running the `setenv('LC_ALL','C')` command. Also, the problem was not limited to GUI apps. I was getting related errors when trying to run `matlab -nodesktop` or `apt-get`. Now everything works as it should.

Comment: Glad to hear that. `LC_ALL` should never, ever be set persistently via the config files on an Ubuntu desktop. You may want to mark your own answer as 'the best', so others see that the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @gunnar-hjalmarsson, I removed `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` from the files: `/etc/default/locale` and `/etc/environment`. I also removed the file: `~/.pam_environment`. Now everything works as expected.

If the above did not work for you, you may want to try [a temporary solution in this link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/126994-locale-system-error) (again suggested by @gunnar-hjalmarsson)

After matlab launches, run

```
setenv('LC_ALL','C')
```

and then it is possible to open `.m` files.

Comment: In 18.04 I get an error, this does not work with 18.04 LTS

Comment: Sadly, I do not have access to a machine with 18.04 and Matlab to check.